# unable to step into a class method gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to step into a method within a class through gdb. So currently, my gdb works for standalone functions. I can step into them fine, however, when I try to step into a method, it doesn't step into it. Here's my script:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{
    public:
        void say_hello(){
            cout<< "hello";
        }
};

int main(){
    test t;
    t.say_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what gdb spits out right after I press run the "run" command.

```
warning: `/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Objects/coretls.build/coretls.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/system_coretls_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_ciphersuites.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_handshake.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_record.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.40.1~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_stream_parser.a"
```

Here's what happens when I try stepping:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:13
13      t.say_hello();
(gdb) s
14      return 0;
(gdb) 
0x00007fff91eec5c9 in start () from /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function start,
which has no line number information.
hello[Inferior 1 (process 9896) exited normally]
```

If it makes any difference, when I run g++ --version, I get Apple LLVM version 7.0.0.
Thanks.

Comment: Not familiar with that particular version of g++ but simple member functions tend to get inlined.  Are you compiling with optimization?

Comment: no, all I'm doing is g++ -g test.cpp, and then gdb a.out

Comment: Using your compile line with g++ --version 5.1.1 on fedora linux I see it step to the member function cout statement.  Sorry to be so helpful.

Comment: @P.Hinker Could you explain your answer again? not sure what you mean.

Comment: Taking your code (above) and compiling it on linux using version 5.1.1 of g++ I can step into the member function as you're trying to do.  It appears that your version of either g++ or gdb is causing the behavior you're seeing.  Which is not very helpful for you, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

By default, GDB steps over functions which contain no debug information. But it is clear that you have it, since you see "at test.cpp:13" when you break on main().

My guess is that you have an older version of GDB that does not fully understand symbols generated by your compiler, and thus fails to step into member functions.

If I were you, I would first try to debug your program with lldb (since you already have it on your system) and see if it goes well. And if it does, then the issue is indeed with an old GDB, so I would upgrade to a later version.

Comment: ok so lldb works for me, I've removed and reinstalled gdb using brew and I still am not able to step into methods. strange.

Comment: And that is your problem. Don't use gdb from homebrew. It's broken. Use either a system-provided one or lldb.